# Return all pairs from a list in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4

This code works in Python 2.7, but not in 3.4.

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools

a = [[3,7,9],[2,7,5],[6,9,5]]

def all_pairs(a, top=None):
    d = collections.Counter()
    for sub in a:
        if len(a)<2:
            continue
        sub.sort()
        for comb in itertools.combinations(sub,2):
            d[comb]+=1
    return sorted(np.array([i[0] for i in d.most_common(top)]).tolist())
```

This is the result I expect:

```
[[2, 5], [2, 7], [3, 7], [3, 9], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 9], [6, 9], [7, 9]]
```

But using Python 3.4, I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    prev_pairs()
  File "", line 102, in all_pairs
    sub.sort()
AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Also, when I add just one element, I get nothing:

```py
all_pairs([3,7,9])
[]

# Expected to get:
[[3,7],[3,9],[7,9]]
```

Is there a better way to write this code to solve both of these issues?

Comment: Mistake on my end, thanks for bringing that to my attention early on.

Comment: I'm also a little confused about what you're trying to do. Why don't you expect `all_pairs([3,7,9])` to produce `[[3,7], [3,9], [7, 9]]`?

Comment: Thanks again erip, [3,9] should be included. You are absolutely a lifesaver.

Comment: Are you really sure you're not replacing this `sub` variable somewhere in your code for a map? The stacktrace makes no sense..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, `map()` produces a `list`, which has the method `sort()`. In Python 3, `map()` produces a `map` object, which acts as a lazy generator and does not have the method `sort()`. If you want to use `sort()` on it, you'll have to pass that object to `list()` first:

```
sub = list(sub)
sub.sort()
```

Of course, if you're doing that, you might as well just use `sorted()`, which works on Python 3 `map` objects as well as `list` objects:

```
sub = sorted(sub)
```

Comment: The Python 3 traceback said it's a `map` object. In Python 2, the `map()` function automatically produces a `list`.

Comment: Also, `sort()` does not return anything. `sub = list(sub).sort()` would assign `None` to `sub`

Comment: @RafaelCardoso - Oh yeah, my bad. I'll fix that now.